# Virtual function doesnt work correctly

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I need to write a program using virtual function of addition and inheritance.
i wrote this 3 classes, but my virtual function doesnt display the result.
it should write the summ of `decimal de("10004")` and `decimal deci("12");` but it just displays `Array->`

how can i possibly fix this?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;


int rev(int);

class Array
{
private:
    string arr[100];
    size_t size;
    string str;
public:
    Array();
    Array(string s)
    {
        str = s;
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    /*{
        cin >> size;
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            arr[i] = '0';
            cout << arr[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }*/
    string& operator[] (const int index);
    Array operator +(Array ar)
    {
        int x = stoi(str);
        int y = stoi(ar.str);
        int d = x + y;
        string s = to_string(d);
        return s;
    }
    virtual void plus( Array *b)
    {
        cout << "Array -> " << str + b->str << endl;
    }
};

string& Array::operator[] (const int index)
{
    assert(index >= 0 && index < size);
    return arr[index];
}


class decimal : public Array
{
private:
    unsigned char dec[100];
    size_t size;
public:
    decimal() : size{ 0 } {}
    decimal(const char* get)
    {
        size = strlen(get);
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--, get++)
        {
            dec[i] = *get;
            cout << dec[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void plus(decimal* b);
    friend decimal operator + (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator - (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator * (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator / (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator % (decimal const &, decimal const &);
};

decimal operator + (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) + rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator - (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) - rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator * (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) * rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator / (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) / rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator % (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) % rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

void decimal::plus( decimal* b)
{
    cout << "Array -> " << atoi((char*)dec) + atoi((char *)b->dec) << endl;
}

int rev(int n)
{
    int  r = 0, remainder;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        remainder = n % 10;
        r = r * 10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return r;
}


class BitString : public Array
{
    char *string;
public:
    BitString() = default;
    BitString(char *str)
    {
        string = new char[strlen(str) + 1]; strcpy_s(string, strlen(str) + 1, str);
    }



    void operator ~()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<strlen(string); i++)
            string[i] == '1' ? string[i] = '0' : string[i] = '1';
    }

    void operator &(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(string) != strlen(a.string))
            cout << "Different lengths" << endl;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.string); i++)
                if (string[i] == '1' && a.string[i] == '1')
                    string[i] = '1';
                else
                    string[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    void operator +(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(string) != strlen(a.string))
            cout << "Different lengths" << endl;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.string); i++)
                if (string[i] == '1' || a.string[i] == '1')
                    string[i] = '1';
                else
                    string[i] = '0';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
            cout << string[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    void operator ^(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(string) != strlen(a.string))
            cout << "Different lengths";
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.string); i++)
                if ((string[i] == '1' && a.string[i] == '0') || (string[i] == '0' && a.string[i] == '1'))
                    string[i] = '1';
                else
                    string[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    void Show()
    {
        cout << string << endl;
    }

    void plus(BitString *b)
    {
        cout << "bitstring -> " << atoi(string) + atoi(b->string) << endl;
    }
};




int main()
{
    int a;
    char str[80];
    Array *arr;
    Array *arr1;
    BitString obj("1010101");
    BitString obj1("1110001");
    decimal de("10004");
    decimal deci("12");
    arr = &de;
    arr1 = &deci;
    arr->plus(arr1);



    system("Pause");

}
```

EDIT:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;


int rev(int);

class Array
{
public:
    string arr[100];
    size_t size;
    string str;
public:
    Array() {  };
    Array(string s)
    {
        str = s;
        cout << str << endl;
    }

string& operator[] (const int index);
Array operator +(Array ar)
{
    int x = stoi(str);
    int y = stoi(ar.str);
    int d = x + y;
    string s = to_string(d);
    return s;
}
virtual void plus(Array *b)
{
    cout << "Array -> " << str + b->str << endl;
}
};

string& Array::operator[] (const int index)
{
    assert(index >= 0 && index < size);
    return arr[index];
}


class decimal : public Array
{
private:
    unsigned char dec[100];
    size_t size;
public:
    decimal() : size{ 0 } {}
    decimal(const char* get)
    {
        size = strlen(get);
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--, get++)
        {
            dec[i] = *get;
            cout << dec[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void plus(Array* b);
    friend decimal operator + (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator - (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator * (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator / (decimal const &, decimal const &);
    friend decimal operator % (decimal const &, decimal const &);
};

decimal operator + (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) + rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator - (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) - rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator * (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) * rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator / (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) / rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

decimal operator % (decimal const &a, decimal const &b)
{
    int x = atoi((char *)a.dec);
    int y = atoi((char *)b.dec);
    int d = rev(x) % rev(y);
    string s = to_string(d);
    return decimal(s.c_str());
}

void decimal::plus(Array* b)
{
    cout << "Array -> " << atoi((char*)dec) + stoi(b->str) << endl;
}

int rev(int n)
{
    int  r = 0, remainder;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        remainder = n % 10;
        r = r * 10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return r;
}


class BitString : public Array
{
    char *string;
public:
    BitString() = default;
    BitString(char *str)
    {
        string = new char[strlen(str) + 1]; strcpy_s(string, strlen(str) + 1, str);
    }

    void operator ~()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<strlen(string); i++)
            string[i] == '1' ? string[i] = '0' : string[i] = '1';
    }

    void operator &(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(string) != strlen(a.string))
            cout << "Different lengths" << endl;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.string); i++)
                if (string[i] == '1' && a.string[i] == '1')
                    string[i] = '1';
                else
                    string[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    void operator +(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(string) != strlen(a.string))
            cout << "Different lengths" << endl;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.string); i++)
                if (string[i] == '1' || a.string[i] == '1')
                    string[i] = '1';
                else
                    string[i] = '0';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
            cout << string[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    void operator ^(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(string) != strlen(a.string))
            cout << "Different lengths";
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.string); i++)
                if ((string[i] == '1' && a.string[i] == '0') || (string[i] == '0' && a.string[i] == '1'))
                    string[i] = '1';
                else
                    string[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    void Show()
    {
        cout << string << endl;
    }

    void plus(Array *b)
    {
        cout << "bitstring -> " << atoi(string) + stoi(b->str) << endl;
    }
};




int main()
{
    int a;
    char str[80];
    Array *arr;
    Array *arr1;
    BitString obj("1010101");
    BitString obj1("1110001");
    decimal de("10004");
    decimal deci("12");
    arr = &de;
    arr1 = &deci;
    arr->plus(arr1);
    arr = &obj;
    arr1 = &obj1;
    arr->plus(arr1);

    system("Pause");

}
```

Comment: Can you try override?!

Comment: tl; dr. Please [edit] your code to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace variable named `string` in `BitString`. It is defined type from `<string>` library in namespace `std` and you use it with `using namespace std;` There is a confusion with naming. For example I renamed `string` to `stringMine` in this example:

```
class BitString : public Array
{
    char *stringMine;
public:
    BitString() = default;
    BitString(char *str)
    {
        stringMine = new char[strlen(str) + 1]; strcpy_s(stringMine, strlen(str) + 1, str);
    }



    void operator ~()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<strlen(stringMine); i++)
            stringMine[i] == '1' ? stringMine[i] = '0' : stringMine[i] = '1';
    }

    void operator &(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(stringMine) != strlen(a.stringMine))
            cout << "Different lengths" << endl;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.stringMine); i++)
                if (stringMine[i] == '1' && a.stringMine[i] == '1')
                    stringMine[i] = '1';
                else
                    stringMine[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    void operator +(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(stringMine) != strlen(a.stringMine))
            cout << "Different lengths" << endl;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.stringMine); i++)
                if (stringMine[i] == '1' || a.stringMine[i] == '1')
                    stringMine[i] = '1';
                else
                    stringMine[i] = '0';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stringMine); i++)
            cout << stringMine[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    void operator ^(BitString a)
    {
        if (strlen(stringMine) != strlen(a.stringMine))
            cout << "Different lengths";
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(a.stringMine); i++)
                if ((stringMine[i] == '1' && a.stringMine[i] == '0') || (stringMine[i] == '0' && a.stringMine[i] == '1'))
                    stringMine[i] = '1';
                else
                    stringMine[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    void Show()
    {
        cout << stringMine << endl;
    }

    void plus(BitString *b)
    {
        cout << "bitstring -> " << atoi(stringMine) + atoi(b->stringMine) << endl;
    }
};
```

Also you need to override `void plus(Array *b)` correctly
`void decimal::plus( decimal* b);` doesn't override it is a new function, it must be

```
void decimal::plus( Array* b)
```

to override. Or for good syntax:

```
virtual void decimal::plus( Array* b) override
```

Also about BitString method, right way to override is to:

```
virtual void plus(Array *b) override
    {
        cout << "bitstring -> " << atoi(stringMine) + atoi(b->stringMine) << endl;
    }
```

But after all you will be need to declare two variables in base class to fix compile errors:

```
class Array
{
public:
    char *stringMine;
    unsigned char dec[100];
```

You call these variables in derived classes from base class.

Comment: `string` is not a keyword, it's a normal identifier.

Comment: @molbdnilo , Yes you are right, sorry I have fixed it in update.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter types are different, you are not overriding in derived classes but simply hiding the base class definition.

It should say

```
    class decimal : public Array
    {
    public:
        void plus(Array* b);
    };

    class BitString : public Array
    {
    public:
        void plus(Array* b);
    };
```

Comment: explicit > implicit. I'd advise to _always_ add the `virtual` keyword on overriden functions when you cannot use C++11's [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).

Comment: I don't. You are welcome to provide your own *separate* answer.

Comment: Are you upset? You're free to revert a suggested edit (I won't push it), but this is the way SO works. Take the [tour] ;)

Comment: @TanveerBadar YSC is right in the matter, it is better to explicitly place `virtual` or `override` or even both; @YSC still, as the answer as is(was) technically is not incorrect even without, editing right away does not really appear appropriate to me, I think instead you should have preferred just leaving a comment...

Comment: i tried replace bitstring and decimal with array, i had to change `private` to `public` in my array class but it thows this now in string file `if (_Errno_ref == ERANGE || _Ans < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < _Ans)
  _Xout_of_range("stoi argument out of range");`

Comment: well, its because my `str` is always `" "` so i keep getting an error when i try to summ a number and `" "`

Comment: You need to first make sure you are calling the correct function. Last two comments sound like bugs in other pieces to me.

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree, but because implicit is hard to read, I overlooked this answer, and I first thought it was incorrect (it is not). I would have reverted my edit if I had enough time to do so.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to call Bitstring or decimal variable in virtual function. i'll edit my question so you can see what i did